# How to add your username to administrator with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

How can I make myself administrator on my PC using powershell ?

Exception:

```
Cannot find group name

+ $AdminGroup.Add($InUser.Path)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember
```

```
$User = $env:USERNAME
$HostName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$DomainName = "xxxx"
$AdminGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$HostName/administrators,group"
$InUser = [ADSI]"WinNT://$DomainName/$User,user"
$AdminGroup.Add($InUser.Path)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could discover the group name by querying `Win32_Group` for the BUILTIN\Administrators group SID:

```bsh
$AdministratorsGroupName = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Group -Filter 'SID = "S-1-5-32-544"').Name
# ...
$AdminGroup = [adsi]"WinNT://$HostName/$AdministratorsGroupName,group"
```